# Response from dialogflow does not come to Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Sometimes Google Assistant does not answer me even though I receive correct response from the fulfillment. That happens only when I use voice command, by using keyboard it always works fine.

[What I receive instead of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCk5g.gif)

It's just 'thinking'.

After using `conv.close('You've punched-in into demo as Jack');` in DialogFlow history I can see following response:

```
{
  "queryText": "Jack",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "[{\"type\":0,\"speech\":\"\"}]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "webhookPayload": {
    "google": {
      "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "You've punched-in into demo as Jack"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "expectUserResponse": false
    }
  },
  "outputContexts": [
    ...
  ],
  "intent": {
    "id": "96f93154-0ae4-4bb4-91c3-c1b796d7cda3",
    "displayName": "punch-in"
  },
  "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
  "languageCode": "en"
}
```

Does any one experienced such issue?

Noticed on Galaxy S7, Android 6.0.1.
actions-on-google v.2.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google assistant team resolved the issues I created to them, and after that the issues is not reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

That mostly happens to me when the internet connection is not good. With voice, there is an extra layer of Voice to Text conversion. Same latency issue might be causing the issue in your case.

Comment: Seems that's not the cause here. As I got, that extra conversion happens before actions on google send request to my fulfillment. But in my case all the requests work well, I'm able to see the response from the fulfillment in a history of dialogflow, but nevertheless assistant does not answer me.